# Need to find web.xml in glassfish server

Tags: glassfish-3, netbeans-6.9, tomcat

I am new to glassfish server.I have used apache tomcat and changed the Built In Servlet Definitions(with param-name=listings) in web.xml  like

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

from false to true to list the files in my html iframe.

How to do it in glassfish server. which file property i have to modify.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Each of your netbeans projects for glassfish has a *web.xml* in:

*project-name/web/WEB-INF/web.xml*

All configurations in this file are used for the project only.

The default configuration (if no web.xml is in project folder) for all glassfish projects is

*glassfish-install-dir/glassfish/domains/domain1/conf/default-web.xml*

If your glassfish domain is not *domain1* replace it with your domain's name.